# How to delete all the "TRANSCRIPTION:" from a file?

Tags: python, file, text, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a text file that contains a list of objects as given below.

> TRANSCRIPTION: സൂക്ഷ്മതയും  പുലർത്തേണ്ടതുണ്ട്. 
> TRANSCRIPTION:  പാലക്കാട് ജില്ലയിലും  കൂടുതൽ ശക്തമായ 
> TRANSCRIPTION: ഇടപെടൽ വേണമെന്ന് തീരുമാനിച്ചിട്ടുണ്ട്.
> TRANSCRIPTION:  തിരുവനന്തപുരം ജില്ലയിൽ
> TRANSCRIPTION:  ട്രിപ്പിൾ ലോക്ക് ഡൗൺ 
> TRANSCRIPTION: പിൻവലിച്ചെങ്കിലും  ജില്ലയിലെ

I wanted to delete all "TRANSCRIPTION:"  from this list and write the result in a text file.
How I can do that in python (Jupyter notebook)?

Answer (score 1):

the string should be:

```
text = "TRANSCRIPTION: സൂക്ഷ്മതയും പുലർത്തേണ്ടതുണ്ട്. TRANSCRIPTION: പാലക്കാട് ജില്ലയിലും കൂടുതൽ ശക്തമായ TRANSCRIPTION: ഇടപെടൽ വേണമെന്ന് തീരുമാനിച്ചിട്ടുണ്ട്. TRANSCRIPTION: തിരുവനന്തപുരം ജില്ലയിൽ TRANSCRIPTION: ട്രിപ്പിൾ ലോക്ക് ഡൗൺ TRANSCRIPTION: പിൻവലിച്ചെങ്കിലും ജില്ലയിലെ"
```

if it is a string you can do

```
text.replace("TRANSCRIPTION:",'')
```

if you want to write that into a file you could do:

```
# note:this will OVERWRITE the current text in the file, 
# if you want to add it to the end just scroll to see other solution
open(filename,'w').write(text)
```

if you want to just append it to the end you can do:

```
open(filename,"a").write("\n"+text)
```

Comment: I had to look twice before I realised that the question is actually in English..... Cheers.

Comment: No. That is a list. When it runs it shows an error

Comment: a list? i supposed the text was a string but if it is a list what are his components?

Comment: This was the actual error: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: this code just works for strings, you didn't specify you had a list object, can you update the question so everyone can understand why you have a list?

Comment: Thanks! Now I have updated the thread

Comment: can you add the code where you added the list?